# javascript date object do not return correct date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working with dates using javascript, and have come across a odd problem

```
                function updateRow(element){
                    var data = element.name.match(/stamp\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/);

                    if(data[2] == 3){
                        var raw = element.value.match(/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);
                        var time = 0;//((raw[1] * 3600) + (raw[2] * 60) + (raw[3] * 1)) * 1000;

                        //Hardcoded just to test
                        var test = new Date("2015-02-18 13:16:06");
                        var date = new Date(test.getTime());

                        document.getElementById(data[1]+"-2").value = 
                                date.getFullYear()+"-"+

                                fillZero(date.getMonth(), 2)+"-"+
                                fillZero(date.getDay(),   2)+" "+


                                fillZero(date.getHours(),  2)+":"+
                                fillZero(date.getMinutes(),2)+":"+
                                fillZero(date.getSeconds(),2);
                    }
                }
```

The date I get from should be the 2015-02-18 13:16:06, but from some odd reason I get 2015-01-03 13:16:06, but I have no idea why.

Comment: month's in javascript start from 0. 0 - jan, 1 - feb

Comment: But the day changes to, 20 becomes 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date.getDate() instead of date.getDay() and add +1 in getMonth

Comment: I will as soon as it will let me.